# Some clarifications about how ant copy some files into a folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am pretty new to ant (I came from Maven and Ant is a nightmare for me !!!)

I have this target:

```
<target name="linuxdriver"
    description="Linux Driver">
    <copy file="${deps.linuxdriver.dir}/${deps.linuxdriver.name}" 
         tofile="${project.datadir}/${deps.linuxdriver.name}"/>
    <copy file="${deps.linuxdriver.dir}/${deps.linuxdriver.name}" 
         tofile="${project.deploy}/data/${deps.linuxdriver.name}"/>
    <chmod perm="+x" file="${project.datadir}/${deps.linuxdriver.name}"/>
    <chmod perm="+x" file="${project.deploy}/data/${deps.linuxdriver.name}"/>
</target>
```

and I have also a property file in which there is definied the "variable" (are named variable?) used in the previous ant code, specifically I have:

```
project.datadir = ${basedir}/data

project.deploy.dir = Release

project.deploy = ${basedir}/../${project.deploy.dir}

deps.linuxdriver.name = atmosfs
```

And now I have some doubts:

1) What represents ${basedir}? A specific directory? What? Reading on the ant manual (http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html) say that this is: **the absolute path of the project's basedir (as set with the basedir attribute of )**.

So, is it the absolute path of my project in the Eclipse workspace?

2) Using the previous information what exactly are the two destination folder in which the files are copied (using the "copy file...to file" tag)?

Comment: For 1: Why don't you just <echo>${basedir}</echo> and see what you get

Comment: For 2: Do the same echo'ing

Comment: Actually, the duplicate is exactly the same question asked by the same person...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) What represents ${basedir}? A specific directory?

Yes. `${basedir}` is the directory where you either started Ant, or the directory specified in the `<project>` entity on the top of your Ant file. Normally, it is set to `"."` which makes it the same directory as the directory that contains your Ant build file.

> 2) Using the previous information what exactly are the two destination folder in which the files are copied (using the "copy file...to file" tag)?

You didn't list your whole Ant file, and your whole properties file. I'm not even sure if your properties file is read in (You need a `<property file="xxxx.properties"/>` near the top of your Ant file).

Assuming that you are executing this in the same directory as your Ant file, and your `${basedir}` is the same directory as your Ant file:

```
<copy file="${basedir}/atmosfs/atmostfs"
    verbose="true"
    tofile="${basedir}/Release/atmosfs"/>
<copy file="${basedir}/atmofs/atmofs"
    verbose="true"
    tofile="${basedir}/../Release/data/atmofs"/>
```

Again, I am assuming `${basedir}` is the directory where your Antfile is stored, and that you are executing the script from that directory.

Notice I have `verbose="true"` in the `<copy>`. I recommend you make that change. This will show you what file is being copied and where when `<copy>` is executed. It's probably the best way to handle this.

By the way, one rule I have is that all action takes place in the project tree. Your last `tofile` is being written outside of the project directory (where I assume your Ant file is located). Imagine someone checking out the project, and finding out that the build process wrote a file outside of the checked out directory and onto his computer in a random place. Doing this is just considered impolite.

Even more polite is to write all files and do all build processing under a subdirectory. Some people use `build`, I prefer `target` because that's a Maven standard. THe idea is that I can clean up the entire build process by simply deleting that one directory.